# Wordpress settings reset after every push to heroku

Tags: wordpress, heroku

On [my heroku-hosted site](http://www.sameetsapra.com), I have a Wordpress Blog. Every time I push to Heroku, my permalinks for the archives and categories are reset and those links are broken. Additionally, the settings for some of my plugins (WP Super Cache) are reset and that plugin is turned off. Although I can easily fix this by going to the Wordpress admin page and turning those settings back on, does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's writing settings to the file system which is reset on each push/restart. The file system is temporary and should not be relied on.

Comment: I understand that, but I was hoping for a more specific answer relating to specific files that I would need to modify.

Comment: Have you seen the wordpress buildpack for Heroku? https://github.com/mchung/heroku-buildpack-wordpress

Comment: No, I have not seen this. I used a template for wordpress on Heroku, like [this one](https://github.com/mhoofman/wordpress-heroku). I already have a site though; would it be possible to use this instead without losing the content in my blog?